# Can we implement group order functionality In Magento 2.3.x

Tags: magento2, orders, place-order

Here is an example of the functionality :

https://www.bigbelly-cluj.ro/ShoppingCart/GroupOrder?CultureID=2&CultureUrl=en

So I want to create a group order functionality which enables initiator user to create an order and then share that order with his/her friends so his/her friends can also add their products to cart and everyone will contribute to cart individually and order will be placed at last by the initiator, and each user will get their share amount of pay with individual share invoice. any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Your requirement looks much interesting and something new. However, this will require much much efforts to customise the existing magento functionality starting from sharing same cart for different login users. You can think for further things step by step. I don't think you find any such ready made extension available on the magento marketplace.

Comment: hi pratik, thanks for your answer. yeah i know this can never be a ready made solution for magento 2, so i was asking because i wanted to see what different areas we could target to implement such a solution like as you said shared cart for different logged in users, partially payment for single order done by different logged in users for their individual share, partial invoices for individual payment etc.  This much as far as i can think of so anything addition to this?

Comment: Vishal, you are right. If I add to your list, then I think you also need to design new structure of order, invoice, shipment and creditmemo which will be shared between all the users and all users can also see their added products in the order separately. This is kind of task in which you will find many such new things to be implemented as you go deep into this. Best of luck :)